# To compare vs To make a comparison with

Tags: word-choice

Example:

1. To compare the calculations, we plot the following graphs.
2. To make a comparison with the calculations, we plot the following graphs.

Which one is better and clearer?

Comment: Are you making a comparison ***with*** the calculations or ***of*** the calculations.  (1. would suggest it's ***of***)

Comment: Thanks. Comparison with. Calculation is like one thing and graphs plotting is another thing. @jim

Answer (score 1):

Compare is an action verb. When you use the term compare your describing the action of assessing one thing and another.
Comparison is a noun, so when you're talking about a comparison, it refers to what was compared.

Ex. I compared the two pairs of scissors together, and the comparison revealed the only difference was in the shape of their handles.

I would go w/choice #2 as it clearly states that information will be there to compare.

Comment: When you're writing, keep in mind that your writing will be much better received if you're diligent about ensuring that your use of *your* and *you're* are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is better.  It is clearer and more concise.  Number 2 is wordier, and it might even be grammatically incorrect.